# form validation in django

Tags: django, file, validation

In which file or form should validation code be written ?

Comment: Since you are new here I won't downvote.
Next time write your problem with more details about what you need.
Also get rid of the multiple question marks.

Comment: Cleaned up, but I can't add the missing info.

Answer (score 5):

In the file where you define the form class.

You might want to read the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) on form validation. There's a decent example on that page of validation [on a form as a whole](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-field-default-cleaning) and on [individual components](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) of forms.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's "forms.py"

Answer (score 0):

Form validation in django is a done by methods on the form class.

Django does not impose any conditions on where forms have to be defined.

They are, often defined, by convention, in a file called `forms.py`

Answer (score 0):

form validation , batter to define in models.py

so at first  you have to define a function  then   you can use this link for more information

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/